# How to ignore the empty cell in the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` and Edit link for each row. I can click on Edit and fill data in the cells of `GridView` and can Update the `GridView` row and the corresponding table in the database is also updated.

I have a save button, which on_click reads each and every row, column by column and perform some action.

The function works fine if all the cell in the `GridView` has some data filled in it. If the cell in the `GridView` is empty, it gives and **error : Input String is not in the correct format.**

The code I have tried is :

```
protected void SAVE_GRID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            string Loc = row.Cells[1].Text;

            string strg = "SELECT Location_Type FROM Quantity WHERE Locations='" + Loc + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(strg, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                Loctype.Text = sdr[0].ToString().Trim();
            }
            con.Close();

            for (int i = 1; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;                   

                string str = "SELECT Profile_Type FROM Profile_Tooltip WHERE Profile_Name='"+header+"'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str,con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    profiletype.Text = dr[0].ToString().Trim();
                }
                con.Close();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[i + 1].Text.Trim()))
                {
                    int n = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[i + 1].Text);
                    //int n = int.Parse(row.Cells[i].Text);

                    for (int m = Asset_List.Items.Count - 1; m >= 0; m--)
                    {
                        Asset_List.Items.Remove(Asset_List.Items[m]);
                    }

                    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                    {
                        Asset_List.Items.Add(string.Concat(profiletype.Text, j));
                    }

                    for (int k = 0; k <= Asset_List.Items.Count - 1; k++)
                    {
                        com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + Label3.Text + " VALUES ('" + Loctype.Text + "','" + Loc + "','" + header + "','" + Asset_List.Items[k] + "')", con);
                        con.Open();
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
              }
           }
        }
        SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Label3.Text + "", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I want to check if the cell is empty, if empty I want to increment to next cell without performing any action for the empty cell.

Kindly help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I have mentioned the error in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use trim and sting function

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[i].Text.Trim() ) )
```

you need to check here

```
 int n = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[i + 1].Text);
```

check the string is convertible to integer or not using parse or tryparse methods of framework

```
short n = 0;
if(Int16.TryParse(row.Cells[i + 1].Text,out n);)
{
  //perform function and user n here now
}
```

Comment: My whole code has been updated in my question. which shows wat exactly I am doing.

Comment: So should I replace  int n = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[i + 1].Text);  to int n = 0;
if(TryParse.int(row.Cells[i + 1].Text,out n);)
{
  //perform function and user n here now
}      ??????

Comment: @ArchanaB.R - the code you are performing after convert cell text to int n gose here in this block..code is updated with the short type just have look

Answer (score 0):

The line that sticks out the most to me is this one:

```
int n = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[i + 1].Text);
```

I usually use something like this to avoid exceptions:

```
int n = 0;  
bool didParse = Int16.TryParse(row.Cells[i + 1].Text, out n);
if (didParse)
{
  //add code here
}
```

Your error might be an exception being thrown because your cell text is empty or perhaps even null.

Comment: This giving me an error too : Error 1:The best overloaded method match for 'short.TryParse(string, out short)' has some invalid arguments.  Error 2:Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out int' to 'out short'

Comment: Haha oops sorry it should have been Int16 n = 0